# Mocking in GO lang

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am new to **Go** and I am still trying to get my head around its concept. I am trying to create a simple unit test and want to `Mock` one of its service. I want to mock `my_mod_2.EmpInfo` in it so that I dont call the actual service.

**method-1.go**

```
package my_mod_1

import (
    "awesomeProject-1/my-mod-2"
)

func CreateAndSendMail() string {
    svc := my_mod_2.EmpInfo{}
    name := svc.GetName()
    empAddress := svc.GetAddress()
    return name + " lives in " + empAddress
}
```

Here is **Emp.go**

```
package my_mod_2

import "fmt"

type EmpInfo struct {}

func (o EmpInfo) GetName()  string{
    fmt.Println("Called actual")
    return "John Doe"
}

func (o EmpInfo) GetAddress() string {
    return "US"
}
```

Here is the **method-1_test.go**

```
package my_mod_1

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestCreateAndSendMail(t *testing.T) {
    val := CreateAndSendMail()
    if val != "John Doe lives in US" {
        t.Error("Value not matched")
    }
}
```

I am seeing `Called actual` in test execution. I Know I have to create a mock using `interface` but I am just not getting it. Can someone please help me out with this small code ?

Comment: *"I am just not getting it"* What are you not getting? Interfaces in general? Or you know interfaces and how to use them but you don't know how to mock them? If you don't understand interfaces, in general, then before you start exploring mocking in Go you should learn those first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to prepare your code to use interfaces and mocks. To do this I suggest you to declare `Service` interface beside `CreateAndSendMail` method. In this case, it is better to pass service instance to the method or use it as an instance variable of a struct to which your method is belong:

```
type Service interface {
    GetName() string
    GetAddress() string
}

func CreateAndSendMail(svc Service) string {
    name := svc.GetName()
    empAddress := svc.GetAddress()
    return name + " lives in " + empAddress
}
```

or

```
type Service interface {
    GetName() string
    GetAddress() string
}

type S struct {
    svc Service
}

func (s *S) CreateAndSendMail() string {
    name := s.svc.GetName()
    empAddress := s.svc.GetAddress()
    return name + " lives in " + empAddress
}
```

Then, your `EmpInfo` will implement your `Service` interface implicitly. And this is a cool feature of golang interfaces. 
After all our preparations, we are ready to create test. To do this, we can implement mocks by ourselves:

```
import (
    "testing"
)

type MockSvc struct {
}

func (s *MockSvc) GetName() string {
    return "Mocked name"
}

func (s *MockSvc) GetAddress() string {
    return "Mocked address"
}

func TestCreateAndSendMail(t *testing.T) {
    svc := &MockSvc{}

    val := CreateAndSendMail(svc)
    if val != "Mocked name lives in Mocked address" {
        t.Error("Value not matched")
    }
}
```

Also, we can use special tool [gomock](https://github.com/golang/mock) to automate mock creation process

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are the most used Go features that helps with testing. Interface in Go allows for Duck Typing where you can switch any type that has implemented an interface to be mocked by a different type.

From your example, the service has the following two methods: GetName() and GetAddress(). Create an interface Service with these two methods.

```
type Service Interface {
    GetName() string
    GetAddress() string
}
```

Now your struct EmpInfo, already implements the Service interface. Create a new MockService struct with same 2 functions.

```
type MockService struct {}

func (ms *MockService) GetName() string {
// Mock Code
}

func (ms *MockService) GetAddress() string {
// Mock Code
}
```

Then, replaces instances of EmpInfo with MockService wherever you need.

PS: Consider adding functions GetName and GetAddress with pointer to EmpInfo.